# First Sale Doctrine applying to physical goods

Tags: patent-infringement, design-patent, trademark, first-sale-doctrine

In an example scenario when a person purchases a 30 pack of Kleenex then makes and sells lunch packs each of which includes a box of Kleenex.  Is this person protected by the First Sale Doctrine to allow them to repackage the Kleenex as such?  (Though as far as I can tell the FSD is intended for copyright work like audio CDs.)  Or is there some explicit/implicit extension to the trademark/patent of a Kleenex?

Comment: In patents it is called "exhaustion" and is more complicated than first sale. Take a look at wikipedia.

Comment: "Exhaustion Doctrine"?